# FASM assembly how to use the FPU in 64 bit programs

Tags: assembly, 32bit-64bit, x86-64, fpu, fasm

I have this code in FASM that calculates a measurement using the FPU that works great in 32 bit programs. How would I convert it so it would run in 64 bit program. when I use this code in the 64 bit program it gives me 0.00000 instead of a number like 54.24457 I think it is something with the FPU instructions but I don't know enough about assembly or 64 bit programming to get it to work

```
macro calculateresultlengthX {

;calculate result length x

;formula is resultlengthX = resultlengthXpixelstextbox / MeasuredlengthXpixelstextbox * MeasuredlengthXtextbox

;read in resultlengthXinpixelstextbox

invoke GetDlgItemTextA, [hwnd], resultlengthxpixelstextbox, bufferbuffer1, 100
cinvoke sscanf, bufferbuffer1, "%f", buffer1 

;read in MeasuredlengthXinpixelstextbox

invoke GetDlgItemTextA, [hwnd], measuredlengthxpixelstextbox, bufferbuffer2, 100
cinvoke sscanf, bufferbuffer2, "%f", buffer2

;resultlengthXpixels / MeasuredlengthXpixels

finit
fld dword [buffer1]
fld dword [buffer2] 
fdivp
fstp qword [buffer3]  

cinvoke sprintf, addr buffer1, "%.16lf", dword [buffer3], dword [buffer3 + 4]
invoke SetDlgItemTextA,[hwnd],resultlengthxtextbox,addr buffer1

;read in ResultlengthXtextbox to get the temporary value

invoke GetDlgItemTextA, [hwnd],resultlengthxtextbox, bufferbuffer1, 100
cinvoke sscanf, bufferbuffer1, "%f", buffer1

;read in MeasuredlengthXtextbox

invoke GetDlgItemTextA, [hwnd],measuredlengthxtextbox, bufferbuffer2, 100
cinvoke sscanf, bufferbuffer2, "%f", buffer2

;answer * MeasuredlengthXtextbox

finit
fld dword [buffer1]
fld dword [buffer2] 
fmulp
fstp qword [buffer3]  

cinvoke sprintf, addr buffer1, "%.16lf", dword [buffer3], dword [buffer3 + 4]
invoke SetDlgItemTextA,[hwnd],resultlengthxtextbox,addr buffer1

}
```

thanks

Comment: AFAIK, the entries for all FPU instructions say say "This instruction’s operation is the same in non-64-bit modes and 64-bit mode" in the manual. Maybe it's something else?

Comment: We don't use the x87 code in 64-bit. We use SSE instructions instead. Every x64 processors supports SSE. Unfortunately x87 instructions are still usable in 64-bit mode; so if you insist you can still use them but your code will be slllooooowwwwww.

Answer (score 1):

The calling convention for doubles in 64 bit mode uses `xmm` registers, you'll have to adjust your `cinvoke` lines if it even supports that. Otherwise just use manual code, something like:

```
lea rcx, [buffer1]
lea rdx, [format]
movsd xmm0, [buffer3]
sub rsp, 32
call sprintf
add rsp, 32
```

Disclaimer: I don't have windows to test.

---

**Update**: `cinvoke` is a helper macro that tries to do the right thing for calling a C function. You are passing the double in two parts, which might work for a stack-based calling convention, but in 64 bit mode registers are used to pass arguments. For doubles you need to use `xmm` registers. The `cinvoke` macro might know how to do that, but you certainly need to help it by telling it you want to pass a double. The code I posted is a hopefully correct calling sequence for `sprintf`, as such you can use it instead of the `cinvoke`.

---

**Update #2**: [msdn says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd2wa36c.aspx) that for varargs functions (and `sprintf` is one) floating point arguments must be duplicated in both integer and xmm registers.
Here is a complete console program multiplying 2 values using the FPU:

```
global main
extern scanf
extern printf
main:
    sub rsp, 40 ; shadow space + stack alignment
    lea rcx, [infmt]
    lea rdx, [op1]
    call scanf
    lea rcx, [infmt]
    lea rdx, [op2]
    call scanf
    fld dword [op1]
    fld dword [op2]
    fmulp
    fstp qword [result]
    lea rcx, [outfmt]
    movsd xmm1, [result]
    mov rdx, [result]
    call printf
    add rsp, 40
    xor eax, eax
    ret
section .data
op1: dd 0
op2: dd 0
result: dq 0
infmt: db "%f", 0
outfmt: db "%.16lf", 0
```

Note this is for `nasm` but you should be able to adapt this to your needs. I have tested this using wine.

Comment: I am sorry but I really dont understand your answer. I swapped out the 5 lines of FPU code with the code u gave me and it compiled but crashed when I tried to calc a value.I will look into xmm. I dont understand what you said about the cinvoke

Comment: I tried to convert just the first cinvoke line to the new code and I put a ret after it to test it out. it compiled fine but when I tried to press the calc button it crashes and says windows can check for a solution and all that stuff.

Comment: in the data i added this format1 db "%f",13,0 and in the code i tried this invoke GetDlgItemTextA, [hwnd], resultlengthxpixelstextbox, bufferbuffer1, 100

lea rcx, [bufferbuffer1]
lea rdx, [format112]
movsd xmm0, [buffer1]
sub rsp, 32
call sprintf
add rsp, 32
;cinvoke sscanf, bufferbuffer1, "%f", buffer1
ret      I also tried reversing the buffer1 and bufferbuffer1 and it still crashed can you please help me also all the buffers like buffer1 and etc are dq ? thank you

Comment: I still can't seem to get this code to work. It crashes on the call sscanf line I asked this question on the fasm site and got this code but it seems to give a empty text boxmov      dword [buffer1],20.0 
mov      dword [buffer2],2.0 
movss    xmm0,[buffer1] 
movss    xmm1,[buffer2] 
divss    xmm0,xmm1 
; char buffer 
lea      rdi,[buffer3] 
lea      rsi,[format0] 
xor      rdx,rdx 
call     qword [sprintf] 
; result string should now be written at buffer3 

buffer1: dd $00000000 
buffer2: dd $00000000 
buffer3: db 256 dup($00) 
format0: db "%0.5f",$00